# Trigger to find gaps in a range

Tags: apex, trigger

There are 2 fields MaxAge and MinAge on Master object(Parent). I have to check If ANY age between MinAge and MaxAge is not covered by the child records, then update Status of the parent to Inactive.

Example :

> Parent : Min = 12 , Max =17.
>
> We have 2 child records ageFrom-ageTo -> 12-14 and 15-17 , this
>   covers all the range between 12-17.
>
> Now suppose the child record data is : ageFrom-ageTo -> 12-13 and
>   16-17 , so I have to detect the GAP, 14-15 and Change Status.

This should happen on Create, update and delete.

```
public with sharing class ageGapAnalysisHelper {
public static void ageGapAnalysis(List<Price_Plan__c> ppRec){
    List<String> servCatList = new List<String>();    
    Set<Decimal> minAgeList = new Set<Decimal>(); 
    Set<Decimal> maxAgelList = new Set<Decimal>(); 
    Map<Id, List<Price_Plan__c>> existingPPs = new Map<Id, List<Price_Plan__c>>();

    for(Price_Plan__c pp : ppRec) { 
        servCatList.add(pp.Service_Catalogue__c);
    }         
    for(Price_Plan__c e : [select id, Service_Catalogue__c, Age_From__c, Age_To__c, Service_Catalogue__r.CatcondMinAge__c,Service_Catalogue__r.CatCondMaxAge__c,            Service_Catalogue__r.Status__c from Price_Plan__c where Service_Catalogue__c in :servCatList AND Id NOT IN :Trigger.New]) {                       
                                            if (!existingPPs.containsKey(e.Service_Catalogue__c)) {
                                                existingPPs.put(e.Service_Catalogue__c, new List<Price_Plan__c>());
                                            }
                                            List<Price_Plan__c> ppList = existingPPs.get(e.Service_Catalogue__c);
                                            ppList.add(e);
                                            existingPPs.put(e.Service_Catalogue__c, ppList);

    }

    for(Price_Plan__c pp : ppRec) {
        if (existingPPs.containsKey(pp.Service_Catalogue__c)) {
            for (Price_Plan__c e : existingPPs.get(pp.Service_Catalogue__c)) {
            //logic in if
                if () 

                {
                   pp.Service_Catalogue__r.Status__c = 'Inactive'; // update Service Catalogue status to Inactive
                }
            }
        }    
    } 
}
```

}

I am getting a map of `Map<Parent Id, List<child Rec>>`, and comparing the existing with the new one. Need to add logic in if.

Comment: Is this a Master Detail relationship? Have you tried to do this using formula field/rollup summary?

Comment: Yes its master detail. If we had to check within a range it was fine. But the scenario is different. We have to check for different ranges within a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using some custom fields.

In your child object, create a formula field to calculate the Gap.

> Field- Gap
>
> Formula: (Age_To__c - Age_From__c)

Next , Create a rollup summary field on th Parent object which will count the number of child.

> Field: CountOfChildren__c
>
> Rollup: Count Of Children.

Next, create another rollup summary field on the Parent object which will sum the Gap field from the children.

> Field: SumOfGap__c
>
> Rollup: Sum Of Gap.

Now, if your status field is a formula field, you can simply update the formula to:

```
IF(
   (CatCondMaxAge__c - CatCondMinAge__c) - (SumOfGap__c + (CountOfChildren__c -1)) == 0, 'Active', 'Inactive' 
  )
```

OR you can do a similar thing using workflow as well if your field is not a formula field.

If the difference between the Gap in Sum of children's gap and parent's gap is 0, means there is no Gap.

Here is a scenario analysis:

[image]

I have seen a comment of yours saying that there is validation rule avoiding the overlapping of max and min ages. So I have taken that into consideration.

Comment: thanks for your help. But the problem here is it depends on the division. Example MinAge =12 and MaxAge=17. And We have 2 child records ageFrom-ageTo -> First Scenario : 12-14 and 15-17  differnce is 4, But if we divide in 3(3 child records) ex. 12-13, 14-15, 16-17 the difference is 3

Comment: That's a very good point. I have updated my answer with another rollup summary field - CountOfChild.

Comment: thanks a ton Santanu. You made it such an easy one. I wudve banged my head on the trigger. Thanks again :)

Comment: Would this method work if there were child records with overlapping age ranges (say `Child 1 - Age_From:12, Age_To:14`, and `Child 2 - Age_From:13, Age_To: 15` for a `Parent 1 - CatCondMinAge:12, CatCondMaxAge:17`)?

Comment: Hi Derek, in my case I have a validation to check overlapping scenarios. but thanks for your help it can be used as solution where overlapping is involved.

Comment: Derek F, I just wanted to come up with situational simple solution as there is a validation rule in place. What you have posted is an excellent approach and I would also have gone that way too, have I not seen wizard's comment about validation rule.

Comment: Glad I could help, wizard. I would really appreciate if you can update the question about your validation rule for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way I can think of to achieve this would be to make use of a `Set<Integer>` (if you're only ever working on a single parent) or `Map<Id, Set<Integer>>` (if there is the possibility of working on more than one parent at a time).

Since the `Map<Id, Set<Integer>>` will work with a single parent as well, I'll just use that in my examples.

The basic idea is this:

- For each parent, take its `CatCondMinAge__c` and `CatCondMaxAge`, and expand that range to an actual list of integers
- Place the parent's integer list into the map
- For each child of the parent, take its `Age_From__c` and `Age_To__c`, and expand that range to another list of integers
- Pull the parent range from the map (the child record will always have its parent's Id)
- Remove the child's range from the parent's range
- After you have iterated over each child, any parent record whose corresponding `Set<Integer>` isn't empty contains a gap and needs to be made inactive

It actually looks like you were on this track yourself. The big difference between our approaches is that I'm using a `Set<Integer>` instead of a `List<Price_Plan__c>`.

An implementation of the algorithm I described above:

```
// I'll be assuming that this is being called from a trigger, and that you already
//   have logic to handle passing the appropriate Price_Plan__c records into this method
public static void ageGapAnalysis(List<Price_Plan__c> ppRec){
    // Gather the Service_Catalog__c Ids, same as your existing code
    Set<Id> serviceCatalogIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Price_Plan__c pp :ppRec){
        serviceCatalogIdSet.add(pp.Service_Catalog__c);
    }

    // Query the Service_Catalog__c records, and build the ranges map
    Map<Id, Set<Integer>> serviceCatalogIdToAgeRange = new Map<Id, Set<Integer>>();

    Set<Integer> tempRange;
    for(Service_Catalog__c catalog :[SELECT Id, CatCondMinAge__c, CatCondMaxAge__c FROM Service_Catalog__c WHERE Id IN :serviceCatalogIdSet]){
        tempRange = new Set<Integer>();

        // A good, old-fashioned for loop.
        // I don't know of any other way to generate the range that we need
        for(Integer i = catalog.CatCondMinAge__c; i <= catalog.CatCondMaxAge__c; i++){
            tempRange.add(i);
        }

        serviceCatalogIdToAgeRange.put(catalog.Id, tempRange);
    }

    // Now we need to query all of the child records.
    // I'm not sure if this query would still pull child records that are in the process
    //   of being deleted.
    // You may have to adjust the logic here a bit.
    // If this query does pull records that are being deleted, you could change
    //   this method to accept 2 arguments (list of recs coming from trigger, list
    //   of recs being deleted), put this query into a Map instead of a list,
    //   and remove the list of records being deleted from the map.
    // I'd prefer that method over using 'Id NOT IN <Ids>', because using 'NOT IN'
    //   can easily make a query non-selective.
    List<Price_Plan__c> allInvolvedPricePlans = [SELECT Id, Service_Catalog__c, Age_From__c, Age_To__c FROM Price_Plan__c WHERE Service_Catalog__c IN :serviceCatalogIdSet];

    for(Price_Plan__c pp :allInvolvedPricePlans){
        tempRange = new Set<Integer>();

        for(Integer i = pp.Age_From__c; i <= pp.Age_To__c; i++){
            tempRange.add(i);
        }

        // here's the important part.
        if(serviceCatalogIdToAgeRange.containsKey(pp.Service_Catalog__c)){
            // I don't expect the above check to be required, but better safe than 
            //   sorry.
            serviceCatalogIdToAgeRange.get(pp.Service_Catalog__c).removeAll(tempRange);
        }
    }

    // One final loop to identify the Service_Catalog__c records that need to be made
    //   incactive.
    List<Service_Catalog__c> serviceCatalogsToDeactivate = new List<Service_Catalog__c>();
    for(Id serviceCatalogId :serviceCatalogIdsToAgeRange.keySet()){
        // If the age range for this service catalog isn't empty, then we
        //   know for a fact that the children don't cover the entire range
        if(!serviceCatalogIdsToAgeRange.get(serviceCatalogId).isEmpty()){
            serviceCatalogsToDeactivate.add(new Service_Catalog__c(
                Id = serviceCatalogId,
                Status__c = 'Inactive'
            ));
        }
    }

    update serviceCatalogsToDeactivate;
}
```